# Returned REST api response is empty

Tags: java, rest, api, jersey

I am using Jersey REST client to invoke a REST api in Java.
My Code looks like below,

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(http://openlibrary.org/api/books).queryParam("bibkeys", "ISBN:0201558025");
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String responseData = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("Response is : " + responseData);
```

I am calling a sample API available in the internet, My program is returning 200 status but returned contents are empty. i.e. `var _OLBookInfo = {};`

when i copy and paste the same link in browser i am getting data like books details. i.e.

```
var _OLBookInfo ={  
   "ISBN:0201558025":{  
      "bib_key":"ISBN:0201558025",
      "preview":"restricted",
      "thumbnail_url":"https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/135182-S.jpg",
      "preview_url":"https://archive.org/details/concretemathemat00grah_444",
      "info_url":"http://openlibrary.org/books/OL1429049M/Concrete_mathematics"
   }
};
```

What is the  problem with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.18/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#queryParam(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) queryParam returns a new webResource, and not modify the current one.
Adding the query parameter as

```
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://openlibrary.org/api/books")
            .queryParam("bibkeys", "ISBN:0201558025");
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion it returns a stream. But when i tried String responseData = response.getEntity(String.class); it still returns empty response.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, why it is not working for you, I have tried locally using `1.19.4` version, and it returned the expected result in the `getEntity(String.class)` call.
What version are you using?
Could you call a `toString` on webresource to check whether it contains the correct URI?

Comment: I am expecting response like this var _OLBookInfo = {"ISBN:0201558025": {"bib_key": "ISBN:0201558025", "preview": "restricted", "thumbnail_url": "https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/135182-S.jpg", "preview_url": "https://archive.org/details/concretemathemat00grah_444", "info_url": "http://openlibrary.org/books/OL1429049M/Concrete_mathematics"}}; but i am getting some html response which doesn't contain the above info. Are you getting the above response ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that response.
What Jersey version are you using? What does the HTML contain, and what is the resulting statuscode?

Comment: I am using jersey 1.10 and my response is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Access to this site is blocked</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/en/Default/master.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/en/Default/security.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> </div> <![endif]-->
<div id="light" class="white_content"></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I have updated the question, please copy the entire snippet and try once. Whether you get the expected response ?

Comment: I have run it via an empty Spring Boot application with 1.10 version, it gives me 
`200
Response is : var _OLBookInfo = {"ISBN:0201558025": {"bib_key": ...`
For whatever reason you are getting 403 error.
Please set your logging level to trace, and check HttpURLConnection logs, it should show you the exact URL and headers.
It should be `{GET /api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0201558025 HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_141}{Host: openlibrary.org}{Connection: keep-alive}`